# .NET framework 3.5 vs. prior versions?

Tags: .net-3.5

Does .NET framework 3.5 include all prior versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **redistributable** does not.

.NET 3.5 supports all of the .NET 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0, 3.0 codebase (although some things may be changed up a bit, marked obsolete, etc...).

But if you install .NET 3.5 you will need to install .NET 1.1 to run an app compiled against that CLR.

However, .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 all share the same CLR so you may be able to run .NET 2.0 apps w/ the 3.5 redist, I'd have to test it to be sure.

Comment: You can indeed run 2.0 apps against 3.5.  As John said, 3.5 just adds set of new assemblies.  Note that 4.0 brings a new CLR, just as 2.0 did.  [Mike Taulty](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/08/03/installing-net-framework-v4-0-and-running-net-2-0-3-0-3-5-3-5sp1-applications.aspx) provides more detail on this topic.

Comment: @landenedge: Thanks for clearing that up. I was almost certain on that one, I just didn't want to state it and end up with my foot in my mouth later :)

Answer (score 2):

.Net 3.0 & 3.5 are considered "Additive releases" which means they are not decoupled from the version 2.0, but more an extension; version 3.0 and 3.5 still use CLR version 2.
So consider version 3 & 3.5 just as version 2 + some (very valuable extra's)

Comment: Very true. This is the history behind how `System.Core.dll` came into existence (when `System.dll` already existed for containing all basic types required by a programmer) which contained all the basic types related to LINQ feature which was the reason behind releasing .Net Framework v3.5. On a similar note .Net v4.5 is also an `Additive Release` over .Net v4.0

Answer (score 1):

3.5 is actually an extension of 3.0, which itself is an extension of 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean.

.NET Framework 3.5 is a set of new assemblies added to .NET Framework 2.0.

.NET Framework 2.0 replaces .NET Framework 1.1